# DbContext.Entry attaching Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

From my research, I read that calling DbContext.Entry(someEntity) would automatically attached the entity to the context.

However, when I do this I find that the entity's state is detached.

Can anyone shed some light on this and how the DbContect.Entry works. I'm using EF 5.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're wanting to attach an object, what you actually want is [DbSet.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). DbContext.Entry is only giving you information about the entity, and allows you to change the state if it's already been attached.

Here's a [good post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676) about entity states from MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer from @Mark Oreta isn't complete:

Following the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676) he posted and reading the whole post revealed some different information: So DbContext.Entry(someEntity) actually is attaching the entity to the context if you set the correlating EntityState you need.

To attach a modified or added entity you could do:

```
using(var yourDbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
    yourDbContext.Entry(yourEntity).State =
        yourEntity.ID == 0 ?
            System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added :
            System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
}
```

To attach an unmodified entity you could do:

```
using(var yourDbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
    yourDbContext.Entry(yourEntity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```