# Updating entity stored outside current DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What's the recommended way of dealing with the following scenario in Entity Framework?

I have some session related data stored in a class called `SessionData` (which uses the Singleton pattern). One of the properties in this class is called `Basket`. The Basket class has a collection of `BasketItems`.

So when the basket is initialised, it gets added to the database and stored in the session:

```
var basket = new Basket();

using(var db = new DataContext())
{
    db.Baskets.Add(basket);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

SessionData.Current.Basket = basket;
```

Then later when a basket item is added to the basket:

```
using(var db = new DataContext())
{
    var basketItem = new BasketItem() { initialisation here }
    SessionData.Current.Basket.BasketItems.Add(basketItem);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This doesn't work because `SessionData.Current.Basket` isn't attached to the current DbContext. I've tried using:

```
db.Baskets.Attach(SessionData.Current.Basket)
```

This works the first time it's called, but fails with the following error on following calls:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

What's the recommended way of doing this update to an entity (and it's hierarchy) that is stored outside the usage of a current DbContext using block?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DbContext.Entry attaching Entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831961/dbcontext-entry-attaching-entity)

Comment: Why does the `SessionContext` have a context? (Or, why _is_ it an EF context?).

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry, I probably confused the question with the name of my SessionContext class. This is nothing to do with DbContext or EF. I'll update my question now to remove this confusion.

Comment: @DanielAuger Thanks, will take a look at that post a bit later on this Evening.

Comment: @DanielAuger Thanks for the link - the link in the answer was a big help. I don't think it's a duplicate question though, as the questions aren't quite the same. It did help me solve my problem though.

Comment: Yup, in hindsight I agree. Vote to close retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be because when I was initialising the properties of the new BasketItem, one of its properties (called `Product`) was tracked by another instance of DbContext. I hadn't spotted it, as I was thinking about the Basket class, not its sub-properties. I solved this by changing the query where I got the product instance from this:

```
var product = (from x in db.Products
               where x.ID == basketRequest.ProductID
               select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

to:

```
var product = (from x in db.Products.AsNoTracking()
               where x.ID == basketRequest.ProductID
               select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which gets the entity instance without it being tracked by the DbContext.

[The link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676) in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831961/dbcontext-entry-attaching-entity) that [Daniel Auger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644/daniel-auger) mentioned in his comment also helped me understand the 'Insert or update pattern', which is what my question was really about. I disagree that the two questions are duplicates, as they're not really the same. Very helpful link though!

Answer (score 1):

In the new db context, retrieve the basket from the database, and then create the new basket items.

Comment: That sounds a bit inefficient given that I already have the basket information in memory.

Comment: Ah, but you don't have it's entity in EF.  I'm interested to see the final solution.